# Trying to Send Email from Preference Screen

Tags: android, android-preferences

I have created preferences XML with Android Preference Activity like so:

```
<PreferenceCategory
      android:title="@string/about">

     <PreferenceScreen
            android:title="@string/customer_support"
            android:summary="@string/email_description">
            <intent android:action="com.sample.android.turboweather.EMAIL_TARA"
             />
    </PreferenceScreen>

</PreferenceCategory>
```

Here is what I declared in my Manifest:

```
 <activity android:name=".EmailTara"
              android:launchMode="singleTop"
              android:screenOrientation="portrait"
              android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation">
          <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.sample.android.turboweather.EMAIL_TARA" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>

          </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

And here is my email activity:

```
public class EmailAccuwx extends SettingsActivity{
    private static final int EMAIL_SUCCESS = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Tara Android Flagship Application");
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"customerservice@tara.com"});
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "");
        emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Email Client Chooser");

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }



}
```

I get this error in logcat:

```
06-07 09:43:52.570: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1517): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.EMAIL_TARA dat=customerservice@tara.com }
```

Any help greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

You've declared your `Activity` in the manifest file as `"EmailTara"` but your activity class is called `"EmailAccuwx"`. Also, your `Activity`'s intent filter lists `"com.sample.android.turboweather.EmailTara"` but in your preferences xml, your creating an `Intent` for `"android.intent.action.EMAIL_TARA"`.

Comment: okay...i've updated my code snippets and now my email sends, but I had to change my email class to extend "SettingsActivity" rather than "Activity."  Also, I can only choose this preference once, it doesn't trigger the start of email SettingsActivity a second time.  Any ideas now?